# Java interface extends Comparable

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I want to have an interface `A` parameterised by `T` `A<T>`, and also want every class that implements it to also implement `Comparable` (with `T` and its subtypes). It would seem natural to write `interface A<T> extends Comparable<? extends T>`, but that doesn't work. How should I do it then?

Comment: I would also refer you to Java Generics FAQ (http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ204), which will give you more ideas regarding `Comparable`.

Answer (score 21):

When `Comparable<? extends T>` appears it means you have an instance of `Comparable` that can be compared to one (unknown) subtype of `T`, not that it can be compared to *any* subtype of T.

But you don't need that, because a `Comparable<T>` can compare itself to any subtype of `T` anyway, e.g. a `Comparable<Number>` can compare itself to a `Comparable<Double>`.

So try:

```
interface A<T> extends Comparable<T> {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
interface A<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Comparable<A<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

depending on whether you need to be able to compare instances of `T` in order to implement your `compareTo` method.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! I came here from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290406/generic-method-to-sort-a-map-on-values. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use comparable you do not need to specify the possibility for subtypes in the compare function, it is by nature possible to pass in any subtype of an object X into a method that declared a parameter of class X. See the code below for more information.

```
public interface Test<T> extends Comparable<T> {

}

class TestImpl implements Test<Number> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Number other) {
        return other.intValue() - 128;
    }
}

class TestMain {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        TestImpl testImpl = new TestImpl();
        testImpl.compareTo(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }
}
```