# Why can't I do this with interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm trying to do something like this, but Java won't let me. I suspect that I am just doing something wrong, but I really have no idea what.

```
public interface PopulationMember extends Comparable<T extends PopulationMember>  {
    int compareTo(T o);
    T merge(T o);
    // Some other stuff
}
```

It seems to think that T should be a class, not a generic type. My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231804/java-interface-extends-), but not exactly the same thing. The point of all that is I want to have a type where I can compare it to other things of the same sub-type without being able to compare them to any other PopulationMember object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface PopulationMember<T extends PopulationMember> extends Comparable<T> {
    int compareTo(T o);
    T merge(T o);
    // Some other stuff

}
```

When you fill in a type parameter (as you do for `Comparable`), you need to provide a class.  If you don't want it to be a specific class, you can parameterize your interface.

Answer (score 4):

```
interface PopulationMember<T extends PopulationMember> extends Comparable<T>  {
    ...
}
```

You specify the generic bounds on the current class (interface), not on the extended one.