# Should i implement or extend comparable to the constructor and how?

Tags: java

i have a class call `Job` which define (jobNumber,executionTIme,priorityLevel) (eg. for constructor Job) im going to use it for `priorityQueue` which is imported and used in other class call JobLine.

I have a method call `compareTo()` in Job class to compare the priority between Job object.

how should implements or extends `Comparable` to Job constructor so that `PriorityQueue` know which to compare the priority.

help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't `extend` `Comparable` as it is an interface, not a class.

Comment: ok, in that case i should implements Comparable to overide the method compareTo to ? i tried and i got error. is there any other way?

Comment: There's no method to override as interfaces don't have method implementations. If you got an error you should include it in your question, along with the relevant code excerpts.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I think I see what you're getting at, but another `interface` could `extend` `Comparable`. I'm just being pedantic though, and you're right in saying that a `class` cannot `extend` an `interface` such as `Comparable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By what you have written, you can simply **implement** (be aware, you can implement an interface but not extend it) it as this:

```
class Job implements Comparable<Job> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Job other) {
        return getPriorityLevel() - other.getPriorityLevel();
    }
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231804/java-interface-extends-comparable) question to understand how to correctly implement the interface.

However, you can use some more "advanced" algorithms considering execution time, and job number, but you have to explain what you want if that's the case.

I didn't understand what you mean by "extend it to the constructor" in the question

Comment: Be aware that `getPriorityLevel() - other.getPriorityLevel()` could result in an integer overflow.

Answer (score -1):

A Class can be `extended` and an interface can be `implemented`

You can read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) tutorial on how to go about implementing an interface.

Comment: This should be post as a comment, not as an answer that completely doesn't explain anything about the question.