# What do the angle brackets mean in this Interface definition?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am relatively new to Java Programming and I came across this declaration of an interface and a class that implements it:

```
public interface Abcd<E extends Comparable<E>>{
......
......
......
}

public class AbcdImpl<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Abcd<E>{
......
......
......
}
```

Can you explain what `<E extends Comparable<E>>` stands for and typically what does `<E>` signify?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to replace < and > with ( and ) in the question? Not interested in people answering maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231804/java-interface-extends-comparable & "E" stands for any data type

Comment: @upcoming_coder: actually that's not an exact duplicate, the linked-to asker already knew about generics, this is more basic.

Comment: <E> is the template name of a generic class. Think of it as Collection_of_<whatever>, for instance.

Comment: is `Abcd<E extends Comparable<E>>` proper syntax, btw ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the syntax mistakes but whenever i was using the <...> it would get commented out from the question.

Answer (score 6):

`E` stand for a type, the letter doesn't need to be E it can be anything, but usually people will use letters like `T`,`K`,`E`,`V`. It makes sense to use a letter that somehow signifies what the type is used for. For instance in the `Map` interface `Map<K,V>`, K is for key and V is for value.

As for `<E extends Comparable<E>>` it means that the type E that is the generic type of `AbcdImpl` needs to itself implement the `Comparable` interface (for itself). So any class `E` has to have a method

```
compareTo(E obj)
```

for comparing one instance of `E` to another instance of `E`.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is a generic type declaration.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

`Abcd<E>` is normally read as "Abcd of E".

For example, List is a list of items, but it's not specified what kind of items.  List is a list of strings, and is a parametrised version of the generic type List.