# How to make a generic concat method in java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, generic-list

I wanted to make a generic method for appending a copy of two linked list together and putting it in another linked list. list a and list b in list c.

here is the code that I have so far.

```
public static LinkedSequence<?> concatenaton(LinkedSequence<?> s1, LinkedSequence<?> s2) throws java.lang.NullPointerException
{
    // Create a new sequence that contains all the elements from one sequence followed by another.
    LinkedSequence<?> concat = new LinkedSequence();
    if(s1 == null || s2 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        LinkedSequence h1;
        LinkedSequence h2;
        h1 = s1.clone();
        h2 = s2.clone();
        concat.addAll(h1);
        concat.addAll(h2);
    }
    return concat;


}

public LinkedSequence<T> clone() {
    // Generate a copy of this sequence.
    LinkedSequence<T> copy = new LinkedSequence<T>();
    //Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element);
    Node<T> curr = first;
    if(getCurrent() == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        while(curr != null) { //iterate through current list
            copy.addLast(curr.getValue());
            curr = curr.getLink();
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

public void addLast(T element) {
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element);
    if (isCurrent() == false) {
        current = newNode;
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
    else {
        //Node newNode = new Node(element);
        last.setLink(newNode);
        last = newNode;
    }
}
```

the clone copies the whole list in a new list.
I keep getting an error saying that I make a generic type in a static type.

Comment: Please share the exact error logs

Comment: @AmanChhabra the error is "Cannot make static reference to the non-static type T"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386295/genericscannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-type-t

Comment: You should be able to do this without cloning by just traversing to the end of the first linked list and pointing to the beginning of second linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is for sure... you need to use a type-parameter in your concat static method to impose the constraint that both input sequences have the same element type like so:

```
public static <E> LinkedSequence<E> concat(LinkedSequence<E> s1, LinkedSequence<E> s2) {
    if(s1 == null || s2 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    LinkedSequence<E> concat = new LinkedSequence<>();
    concat.addAll(s1);
    concat.addAll(s2); 
    return concat;
}
```

I took the liberty of edit the code a bit removing what seem to be redundant or inefficient.

You can make it a bit more general and accept inputs that contains type that are subclasses of the return type:

```
public static <E> LinkedSequence<E> concat(LinkedSequence<? extends E> s1, LinkedSequence<? extends E> s2) { ... }
```

You probably will need to change the `addAll` definition to accept `? extends E` rather than `E` typed input collections.