# Cannot make static reference to the non-static type t

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a static method that returns a Generic Object of the same class which the static method is a member of but there is compilation error on the return type as

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T

Looking at other solutions on stack overflow I found this 
[(Generics)Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386295/genericscannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-type-t)

where a responder has provided an answer which says that for static methods, we must also include the target type  before the return type but even this does not work

```
public class Condition<T extends Node> {

private boolean isInitialized=false;
private ConditionType type;
private NodeType nodeType;
private String propertyName;
private Predicate<T> onlyIfTest;
private Predicate<T> predicates;

private Condition() {

}

//Here at the return type i get the error Cannot make static...
public static Condition<T> include(NodeType type,String propertyName) {
    Condition<T> condition = new Condition<T>(); //and an error here too
    condition.type = ConditionType.INCLUDE;
    condition.nodeType = type;
    condition.propertyName = propertyName;
    condition.isInitialized =true;
    return condition;
}
```

The error that i get is Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T. How can i make it work with a static method.

Comment: T is only set to a type when the class is instantiated.

Comment: Each instance of `Condition` has its own generic type `T`. There's nothing in the static method indicating what `T` is supposed to be. You could add `<T>` as a generic type parameter to the static method if that's what you want.

Comment: @khelwood can you show as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already had your answer:

> we must also include the target type before the return type

but didn't apply it.

```java
public static <T extends Node> Condition<T> include(NodeType type, String propertyName)
```

Comment: Thanks Julia but somehow even that is not working. You can try that and let me know if the results are different. I think its got something to do with me returning the object of the same class from the static method

Comment: @RaghaveShukla Sorry, my bad. I didn't notice the generic type extends `Node`. Check the edited answer and let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Perfecto ! Thank you very much. Now i have a cleaner code :)

Answer (score 3):

Each instance of `Condition` has its own generic type `T`. There's nothing in the static method indicating what `T` is supposed to be. You could add `<T>` as a generic type parameter to the static method if that's what you want.

For example:

```
public static <T extends Node> Condition<T> include(NodeType type, String propertyName) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong

```
public class Condition<T> {
//...

    public static <T> Condition<T> include() {
    Condition<T> condition = new Condition<T>();
    return condition;
    }

}
```