# How do I instantiate my class extending from ArrayList having any type?

Tags: java, generics

I have class ReadOnlyList extending from ArrayList of generic types.

```
public class ReadOnlyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
        
    public ReadOnlyList(ArrayList<T> list) {
        super(list);
    }
    
    public boolean add(String s) throws UnsupportedOperationException{
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add("abc");
        myList.add("xyz");              
                
        ReadOnlyList<T> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyList<T>(readOnlyList);
    }
}
```

`ReadOnlyList<T> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyList...` is giving compiler error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T. I understand the error(an instance should have a specific type like String, not T. But my question is : How do I instantiate instance of type `ReadOnlyList<String>` via `ReadOnlyList(ArrayList<T> list)` itself without making it private?

Isn't there any other way provided by Java generics? Any url pointer to the specific need also will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Generics)Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386295/genericscannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-type-t)

Comment: Why not `ReadOnlyList<String> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyList<>(readOnlyList);`?

Comment: Don't extend `ArrayList` - check Effective Java as to why. Extend `AbstractList`.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter : The suggection in the url : makes the constructor private and exposes newInstance method as public. This was not what I was looking for, though this is removing the error. Isn't there any other way provided by Java generics? Any url pointer to the specific need also will do

Comment: Please use inline code formatting, especially with code that includes things inside `<` and `>` like in `ReadOnlyList<String>` otherwise this site doesn't display it properly, causing a lot of confusion

Comment: Don't extend `ArrayList`. Aside from anything, this doesn't stop you adding to the list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the type when you declare the ReadOnlyList:

eg:

```
ReadOnlyList<String> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyList<>(myList);
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this is the right answer.

Comment: Gave the same compiler error when I tried the above code. Let me know if it works on ur machine.

Comment: yes - main method is attempting to use/instantiate the `ReadOnlyList`, but the question asks something like, how can I create `ReadOnlyList<String> readOnlyList` by supplying an `ArrayList<T>`... of course `ArrayList<T>` would need to be `ArrayList<String>` for this to work... if so, unpack the elements from the list into the `ReadOnlyList` - the logic would then go in the constructor to perform this action.

Comment: If you amend the last line of your `main` method to the one I posted above, you will have a `ReadOnlyList<String>`. If however you want to create it using `new ReadOnlyList<>(new ArrayList<String>())` your constructor needs to unpack the `String` Elements from the ArrayList, and effectively remove the ArrayList wrapper away.

Answer (score -1):

The actual problem you're reporting is because you're trying to access the type variable, `T` - which is associated with an instance of `ReadOnlyList` - in a static method, which is not associated with an instance of `ReadOnlyList`.

You would need to use a symbol which is in scope, for example:

```
ReadOnlyList<String> readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyList<>(readOnlyList);
```

---

Your list is *far* from read-only:

- You can still set its elements
- You can remove elements
- You can add elements using the `add(int, E)` overload
- You can probably add elements through `addAll` and `subList(...).add`

You don't really need to reinvent this: `Collections.unmodifiableList` gives you a standard way to achieve this, as well as `List.of` in newer versions of Java, `ImmutableList` in Guava etc.

And you can roll your own, by extending `AbstractList`. That provides a skeletal implementation of the methods, and the Javadoc has instructions for which methods to override for read-only, writable but fixed size, variable-sized lists etc.

Comment: I know it is not complete...but that was a sample code. Also sometimes, we try to do things even if it is available in one line like Collections.unmodifiableList. This is more to understand how make things work when I need something like this.